# Azure command-line task - What is the difference between 'Fail on standard error' and 'Continue on error (unchecked)'?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In Azure command-line task, what is the difference between:

1) Fail on standard error

2) Continue on error (unchecked - set to false)

And What is a standard error?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the tasks look on the exit code, for example, in the Command Line task, if the exit code is `1` the task will fail with an error.

So if you have an incorrect command line, for example:

```
echooo "test"
```

The task will fail.

If you check the `Continue on error` so even the exit code will be the task will fail bit the pipeline will continue and he will be in orange color, it will be in orange color (partially succeed).

But, if you write something to the stderr, for example:

```
echo test 1>&2
```

In a regular way the task will not fail and will be green. but if you check the `Fail on standard error` the task will fail even the command is correct.

Comment: So what exactly is the purpose of 'Fail on standard error'? Does echo mean standard error?

Comment: No, only `echo` with `1>&2` (this mean to write to stderr - standard error) and also cases that the exit code is ok but some error is written to the stderr.

Comment: What is meaning of 1>&2

Comment: Move the output to the `stderr` instead of `stdout`.

Comment: Which output is moved? Can you give me an example of point to relevant article. I thought it checks if 1 is greater than 2.

Comment: echo "test", the "test" is output, a regular output (stdout), but if you redirect it with 1>&2 you say to the cmd that is error output.

Comment: You're welcome! I don't a specific article, but you can google it :)

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops):

> failOnStandardError: (Optional) If this is true, this task will fail when any errors are written to the StandardError stream. Unselect the checkbox to ignore standard errors and rely on exit codes to determine the status
>   Default value: false

This means that any command that writes an error to the host causes the task to fail. Example:

```
Write-Error "I will cause the task to fail."
```

The second thing "Continue on error" is a task setting, which indicates whether the pipeline should proceed executing tasks. If this is enabled, even if the task fails it will continue processing others.

Comment: Whay is StandardError. Are there manu types of erroes like standard, non standard?

Comment: As Shaiky already mentioned the default reason for powershell to fail is the exit code (Check: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams). 
Now let's assume we have a method as follows:

$address = $null
if ($address -eq $null) {
   Write-Error "The address field is null." 
}
Write-Host "Skipping address".

This is a perfectly fine statement and will even write the "Skipping address". Now it's up to you if you want the task to fail or not. If you decide to "fail on standard error" the task will not rely on the exit code and fail due to the "Write-Error" statement.

Comment: But my question was about command line task. What is standard and non standard error in command line task?