# What are the ways in which one can communicate error to the azure pipeline via powershell?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-tasks

Assuming I am using a Powershell script task to perform some complex things, I want to let the azure pipeline know about the errors.

I know that using exit(0) is success and any non zero exit is a failure which will cause the azure pipeline task to fail (unless continue on error is enabled).

2nd approach is to use write-error which is same as above.

3rd approach is to use write-error to send the output to the stderr via powershell and then on the azure pipeline task set 'Fail on standard error' to true (check-mark). This approach can be used on its own and also along with both the above approachs.

Are there any other ways that I am missing?

Comment: How is it going with this case? Any good news?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `Write-Error` the task will fail even if **Fail on standard error** not checked.

Another option is to use a[logging command](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) `task.logissue`:

```
##vso[task.logissue type=error;sourcepath=consoleapp/main.cs;linenumber=1;columnnumber=1;code=100;]this is an error
```

Results:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it mean that this is incorrect: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58621359/1779091 (It says: this means that any command that writes an error to the host causes the task to fail. Example: Write-Error "I will cause the task to fail.")

Comment: Right, you can check it easily :)

Comment: I have updated my question to include the correction (of write-error). Please can you tell me what exactly is the use case of "Fail on standard error" in a powershell task? Is it useful when we write-error to stderr output, instead of just write-error?

Comment: @variable I didn't check it deeply :/